# Differences between adoptNode and importNode

Tags: javascript, document, xmlnode

What are differences between `importNode` and `adoptNode` on Document object in JavaScript?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can think of `adoptNode` as "move", and `importNode` as "copy".

w3schools `adoptNode()` reference:

> Note: The original node (and its child nodes, if any) is removed from the other document.

w3schools `importNode()` reference:

> Note: The original node is not removed from the other document. The imported node is a copy of the original.

Note the `deep` parameter in `importNode()`.